# Use of 'nigh' in fiction

Tags: fiction, vocabulary, sentence-structure

First post here.

Some background first: I write follow ups to my Pathfinder table session from the perspective of my character. These are shared, and read along with other player's own contributions.

I would like to create emphasis on the peril of the current situation. Here is my sentence:

> Where there are many, violence is nigh guaranteed.

I really like the use of nigh, but worry that it simply does not fit along side guarantee. Should I stop trying to fit a square into a circular hole?

Comment: This is an extremely contextual question, as a rule we don't answer questions about _what_ you should write, in terms of structure or vocabulary, you'll probably have better luck on [english.se].

Answer (score 1):

The short answer here is yes, but the long answer is that 'nigh' could be replaced with better words ('all but guaranteed' is my personal edit here).

Being frank, you should never shape your style around a 'favourite word' or 'word of the month'. There's a reason *Twilight* is so roundly mocked for its overuse of the word 'chagrin'; a discerning reader can see that Stephenie Meyer clearly liked the word, and thus overused it with childish glee, even when (or especially when) it was inappropriate.

Comment: thanks! I think within the setting of a fantasy tabletop game, it will work. That said, I'm going to keep a tally while I edit each email. A new email every week that seems to include "nigh" would definitely be in poor taste. 

P.S. I hadn't know about the _Twilight_ trivia, that's pretty funny. Thanks for the help!

edit: I should mention that I am going to take your immediate advice move away from 'nigh' in this particular use. I'll save it in my tool belt for the future.

Answer (score 1):

"Where there are many, violence is nigh guaranteed."

The sentence doesn't read well because "nigh" means "near". As in, the "end is nigh"

So, perhaps read it again as "Where there are many, violence is near guaranteed." To me, that doesn't sound like it has the gravitas you're after. The end is nigh sounds final and fast approaching anyway, so the guarantee isn't needed.

Try "Where there are many, violence is nigh."